# Converting a CImg data struct to .Net bitmap class

Tags: c#, c++, cimg

I have a C/C++ dll that I use to generate some informations, and, a image from this informations, now, I need to use this dll in C#.
I have implemented a exported function that write all the CIMg::data into a pre-allocated buffer.
So, I tried to convert this pre-allocated buffer into a Bitmap in C#, but, the image has been generated with just some wrong lines...
After this, I tried to implement an alternative version of this functions, that write into a pre-allocated buffer, all the RGB from the image, but, when the system write the image, the image is mirrored.

This is my function to save all the RGB:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> SystemImage::getData()
{
    if(!_generatedImage)
        this->createImage();

    std::vector<unsigned char> data;

    unsigned char red, blue, green;
    for (int x = 0; x < _baseImage->width(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _baseImage->height(); y++)
        {
            red = (*_baseImage)(y, x, 0, 0);
            green = (*_baseImage)(y, x, 0, 1);
            blue = (*_baseImage)(y, x, 0, 2);

            data.push_back(red);
            data.push_back(green);
            data.push_back(blue);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

My C# function to handle this information:

```
    public Bitmap CreateImage()
    {
        const uint bufferSize = 6113880;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        Bridge.System_Bridge.getRGBData(PSystem, data, bufferSize);

        int position = 0;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1332, 1530);
        for (int x = 0; x < 1332; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 1530; y++)
            {
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(data[position], data[position + 1], data[position + 2]));
                position += 3;
            }

        data = null;

        return bmp;
    }
```

There is a more better way to make this ?
How I can use the CIMg::Data to make the bitmap ? ( This will reduce a lot of allocated memory!! )

Comment: are we talking bitmap the file format family? If so you can't just write the data into a file. You need to format the data as outlined in the file format specification and write the proper headers.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This has nothing to do with **CImg** http://cimg.eu